# Domain mapping is not working for linux web hosting

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, web-hosting

I am trying to map my domain with my server having static IP. My server is Linux based and here is more info about my sever
Apache/2.2.27  mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4
My web app is in PHP and hosted on my server. 
I mapped my domain using A record. Now after mapping, my domain is redirecting to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi instead of display my web site. Another domain that was already mapped to my web hosting is correctly showing the website. Is there anything I have to do on my hosting to allow my new domain?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure VirtualHost for your new domain. Read the official [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: Is there any limit on how many domains I can map on single IP. Because in my case, I need to map a very large number of domains to my server(over 3000 and number grows with new clients coming). Plus is there any way to automate the process. Sorry I have no knowledge about linux and apache

Comment: No there is no limit for this. But after adding new virtualhost you need to restart apache. You can create *.domain.com record to map to your server IP in DNS and than create scripts to update vhosts records  serverside.

Comment: "Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address" is this applicable in my case, because I have to serve single website on a single IP with multiple domain names.

Comment: For you new site - new VirtualHost (because of you already has one for the previous site, mapped to this server. But for subdomain or aliases of you site: ServerName domain.com; ServerAliase first.domain.com; ServerAlias second.domain.com; ServerAlias newdomain.us; you can set in one VirtualHost.